# How to move up and down rows in a table and show the row content in a new div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table for users to edit and view. I want to show the row content in a div, starting with the first row in the table. Then I want the user to be able to click an up or down arrow and display that new row content in the div.

Here is my html div where the row content will go:

```
            <div id="rowEditDiv">
                <div id="arrowIconsDiv">
                    <img src="images/up-arrow.png" class="arrowIcons" id="arrowUp">
                    <img src="images/down-arrow.png" class="arrowIcons" id="arrowDown">
                </div>
                <div id='editableRowToEdit'></div>
            </div>
```

Here is my html table:

```
<table id='fileTextTableId'>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 1</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 2</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 3</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 4</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 5</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>6</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 6</pre></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my JS:

```
        var table = document.getElementById("fileTextTableId");
        var row = $(".rowToEdit");
        var rowContent = table.rows[0].innerHTML;
        //empty row
        $("#editableRowToEdit").empty();
        //draw arrows, form for specific row, and save btn
        $("#editableRowToEdit").append(row);

        $("#arrowUp").on("click", function() {
            $("#editableRowToEdit").empty();

            var rowUp = row.closest('tr').prev('tr');
            console.log(rowUp);
            $("#editableRowToEdit").append(rowUp);

        });
        $("#arrowDown").on("click", function() {
            $("#editableRowToEdit").empty();

            var rowDown = row.closest('tr').next('tr');
            console.log(rowDown);
            $("#editableRowToEdit").append(rowDown);
        });
```

The JS code I have now doesn't show any new row content in the div and when I console log it, it shows all the rows in the table.

Comment: what do you mean show the row data?  When you have a table, all the information is shown, unless you have a hidden object holding information.  I feel generally speaking, you need to flush out this concept more with some classes showing visibility, etc.

Comment: You have same class on rows as on container ... and can't append a `<tr>` to a `<div>` it's invalid html

Comment: The user will only be able to edit one row at a time. That's why I'm showing the row contents inside a new div. This way they can change the content and then save the new data.

Comment: @charlietfl i see what you mean.. I changed the id of the div so there is no issues

Comment: whole logic using `closest` is wrong. Suggest you simply add a class `selected` and work from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var row = $(".rowToEdit");
```

This means ***all your rows*** (because all of them have this class).

... and later on:

```
var rowUp = row.closest('tr').prev('tr'); // and
var rowDown = row.closest('tr').next('tr');
```

If you look at [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/), they return next or previous sibling of ***each element in collection***. Which means `rowUp` will hold all rows except last and `rowDown` will hold all rows except first.

You probably want to begin by selecting

```
var row = $(".rowToEdit").eq(0)
```

Or `$(".rowToEdit").first()`. After this your script will start working as you expect.

---

I guess this is what you're looking for?

```js
var ftt = {
  rTE : $(".rowToEdit").eq(0),
  eRTE : $("#editableRowToEdit"),
  aU : $('#arrowUp'), 
  aD : $("#arrowDown"),
  place : function(row) {
    ftt.eRTE.empty();
    ftt.eRTE.append(row.clone())
  }
}

ftt.place(ftt.rTE);

ftt.aU.on("click", function() {
  var prev = ftt.rTE.prev();
  ftt.rTE = prev.is('tr') ? prev : ftt.rTE;
  ftt.place(ftt.rTE);
});

ftt.aD.on("click", function() {
  var next = ftt.rTE.next();
  ftt.rTE = next.is('tr') ? next : ftt.rTE;
  ftt.place(ftt.rTE);
});
```

```css
#editableRowToEdit {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-table;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.arrowIcons {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
#arrowIconsDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}
#rowEditDiv {
  max-width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rowEditDiv">
  <div id="arrowIconsDiv">
    <span class="arrowIcons" id="arrowUp"></span>
    <span class="arrowIcons" id="arrowDown"></span>
  </div>
  <div id='editableRowToEdit'></div>
</div>
<table id='fileTextTableId'>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='rowToEdit'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <pre>Some content will go on row 1</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='rowToEdit'>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <pre>Some content will go on row 2</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='rowToEdit'>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <pre>Some content will go on row 3</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='rowToEdit'>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>
        <pre>Some content will go on row 4</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='rowToEdit'>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <pre>Some content will go on row 5</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='rowToEdit'>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>
        <pre>Some content will go on row 6</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: when I click to move rows nothing shows up in the div. When I console log the response on click it's this: [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document]

Comment: not sure it's actually picking up the next or prev row content.

Comment: From what you describe, it looks like you don't have an element with `id="editableRowToEdit"` in your page. Any errors in the console?

Comment: the editableRowToEdit is the div where the row content is appended when clicking the up or down arrows

Comment: Ok, let me test, please

Comment: why are you now declaring one variable with all the others inside the one variable?

Comment: I'm a bit perfectionist, I didn't like the fact that it poluted the global space with too many variables, so I took the liberty placing them in a single object. `ftt` (from FileTextTable).

Comment: okay perfect, that makes sense to me. I was just a little confused. Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: Global variables polution is prone to variable naming collisions. They're extremely hard to find bugs. When inside your own object, you know nothing can go wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the tip and advice. I still have a lot to learn about JS

Comment: I know I asked this question last week.. but is there a way I can record what index number we're at when clicking through the rows and stop at a certain index number or if that index number doesn't match the page number. Take a look at my code review question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161913/how-to-display-row-based-on-index-number

Comment: @Teton-Coder yes, there is. Inside the on('click', function(){}), you can get the index of the current row using `ftt.rTE.index()`. First element has index `0`. Based on comparison with this `index()` you can decide whether or not to make the change.

Comment: Is there a way I can use the index with the new code I created, that is on the codereview question? I had to modify it a little bit because some data from the database changed.

Comment: I wanted to create a map of the object of arrays, but I couldn't figure out how to do it so I just created my own index variable and am clicking through it that way. I know this isn't the best way to do it. Do you have any suggestions on how to better code it? Thanks!

Comment: That question doesn't make much sense to me. You get some data and than you call two functions, but nobody knows what those functions do, except you. You need to create a working example (eventually using some dummy data) and clearly state what is the desired behavior. I find that question unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: I modified it.. I forgot to take those out. One isn't needed and then I updated the other function to fully show what's going on.

Comment: I don't really understand why you posted it on CR. On CR you only post code that works but you want to improve (or find out if there are better ways to do it). You need to ask on SO when you don't know how to do something.

Answer (score 3):

```js
 var table = document.getElementById("fileTextTableId");
var row = $(".rowToEdit");
var rowContent = table.rows[0].innerHTML;
//empty row
$("#rowToEdit").empty();
//draw arrows, form for specific row, and save btn
$("#rowToEdit").append(rowContent);

$("#arrowUp").on("click", function() {
 var currentTdNo =  $("#rowToEdit td").html();
 var prevTdNo = parseInt(currentTdNo) - 1;
 $(".rowToEdit").each(function(){
  var interatioNo = $(this).children('td:first').html();
  if ($.trim(interatioNo) == $.trim(prevTdNo)) {
   var tdData = $(this).html();
   $("#rowToEdit").empty();
   $("#rowToEdit").append(tdData);
  }
 });
});
$("#arrowDown").on("click", function() {
 var currentTdNo =  $("#rowToEdit td").html();
 var nextTdNo = parseInt(currentTdNo) + 1;
 $(".rowToEdit").each(function(){
  var interatioNo = $(this).children('td:first').html();
  if ($.trim(interatioNo) == $.trim(nextTdNo)) {
   var tdData = $(this).html();
   $("#rowToEdit").empty();
   $("#rowToEdit").append(tdData);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rowEditDiv">
 <div id="arrowIconsDiv">
  <img src="images/up-arrow.png" class="arrowIcons" id="arrowUp">
  <img src="images/down-arrow.png" class="arrowIcons" id="arrowDown">
 </div>
 <div id='rowToEdit'></div>
</div>
   
<table id='fileTextTableId'>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 1</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 2</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 3</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 4</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 5</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rowToEdit'>
            <td>6</td>
            <td><pre>Some content will go on row 6</pre></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check the above code, its working fine now. In case of any issue revert me

Comment: Why not just remember/change the row, like in the original script? I mean, at least there the architecture was good. All OP needed was a bit of cleanup. You're checking/cloning all `<td>`s on each click. Why? It's extremely inefficient.